# JavaFX 2.x : Chart Content space to the right

Tags: css, charts, javafx-2

I would like to set how much empty space from last data point plotted to the rightmost chart content.

In example, in the picture below

[image]

I mean the empty space from where lines ends (Dec X position) to the rigthmost part of the chart.

Is there a way to set this value and possibly, in css?

Thanks

Comment: Found a solution, question closed.